# QML: Setting a row width in a ListView

Tags: qt, layout, qml, row

I have a page with a ListView in a layout. The ListView consists of several rows represented with Rectangles and a RowLayout in it. The RowLayout itself consists of Text elements. The problem which I'm facing is that I can't properly set the width of these Text elements. E.g. I want the first Text element to have a 1/3 width of the whole row. The way I'm setting it now makes the Text element width to be cca 3/4 of the row width, at least visually it looks like that. What would be the proper way of setting the Text element width?

```
Item {
  ColumnLayout {
    anchors.fill: parent

    // some components here ...

    Rectangle {
      width: parent.width
      Layout.fillWidth: true
      Layout.fillWidth: true

      Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: 0.1 * parent.height

        ListView {
          id: listView
          anchors.fill: parent

          model: SomeModel {}

          delegate: Rectangle {
            height: 40
            width: listView.width

            RowLayout {
              width: listView.width

              Text {
                Layout.preferredWidth: 0.3 * listView.width
                text: "text1"
              }
              Text {
                text: "text2"
              }
              // some other Text elements ...
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Try to add `Layout.fillWidth: true` to the second `Text` element.

Comment: @folibis Thanks, it seems that's it. Post it as an answer, I'll accept it.